# Python: Upgrading Pandas Keeps old version

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, package, installation

I am trying to upgrade to a new version of pandas. It says it installs successfully but whenever I use `pd.show_versions()` it still gives the old version of

```
pd.show_versions() 
commit: None
python: 3.5.2.final.0 
pandas: 0.23.0
```

Here is the installation success:

```
[env] C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\tmp>pip install --upgrade pandas --user
Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in c:\users\me\lib\site-packages (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.12.0 in c:\users\me\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\me\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2016.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\me\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in c:\users\me\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.10.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a virtual environment, you have to `pip install` without the `--user` option in order to install `pandas` in your virtual environment

So

`pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: when I do that, it gives me this error `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:`

Comment: try running as admin